# Android OrmLite pre-populate database

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

Is it possible with OrmLite to create a sql script file to easily populate the database with data?  I did some searching and couldn't come up with anything easy.  I know I can create some objects with data, I'm just looking for a cleaner method.

I'm thinking create a script file, open a a reader at load, and process each file as raw SQL the executeRaw() method.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good one Joe.  I think your idea of the `executeRaw()` is close but use `updateRaw()` instead.  Update handles `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` statements.

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-update

You should call `TableUtils` to create your schema first of course:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/tableUtils

Hope this helps.  You may want to use the mailing list for questions in the future:

> http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user/

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to post my solution for anyone who might need it

```
try {
    tableDAO.updateRaw("DELETE FROM table");
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.populate_db);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        tableDAO.updateRaw(strLine);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I have some questions though. Where did you put this in your code? And what is the tableDAO.updateRaw"DELTE FROM table" doing? Also if someone else sees this remember to have each INSERT in your file in 1 line.

Comment: I was using this code for testing purposes, but hypothetically you can put it anywhere as long as the tables have been initialized.  Putting it somewhere in the main activity onCreate is fine.  If you are inserting a lot of data I would recommend spawning a separate thread or AsyncTask, though.  The DELETE FROM command is dropping all existing data in the table to clean things up first.