# Ormlite Android bulk inserts

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, ormlite

can anyone explain why my inserts are taking so long in Ormlite? Doing 1,700 inserts in one  sqlite transaction on the desktop takes less than a second. However, when using Ormlite for Android, it's taking about 70 seconds, and I can see each insert in the debugging messages.

When I try and wrap the inserts into one transaction it goes at exactly the same speed. I understand that there is overhead both for Android and for Ormlite, however, I wouldn't expect it to be that great. My code is below:

```
    this.db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dao = db.getAddressDao();
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.poi)));
    try {
        dao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] columns = line.split(",");
                    Address address = new Address();
                    // setup Address
                    dao.create(address);
                } 
            return null;
         }
        });
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this may be "expected".  I get similar performance when I do that number of inserts under my emulator as well.  The batch-tasks and turning off auto-commit don't seem to help.

If you are looking to load a large amount of data into a database, you might consider replaying a database dump instead.  See here:

> [Android OrmLite pre-populate database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054974/android-ormlite-pre-populate-database)

Comment: I've found an [easy workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27315301/264047). Probably that'll give you an idea what's going wrong. (And thanks for you hard work)

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same problem, and found a reasonable workaround. This took insert time from 2 seconds to 150ms:

```
final OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper myDbHelper = ...;
final SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try{
    // do ormlite stuff as usual, no callBatchTasks() needed

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

**Update:**

Just tested this on Xperia M2 Aqua (Android4.4/ARM) and `callBatchTasks()` is actually *faster*. 90ms vs 120ms. So I think more details are in order.

We have 3 tables/classes/DAOs: Parent, ChildWrapper, Child.
Relations: Parent to ChildWrapper - 1 to n, ChildWrapper to Child - n to 1.
Code goes like this:

```
void saveData(xml){
    for (parents in xml){
        parentDao.createOrUpdate(parent);
        for (children in parentXml){
            childDao.createOrUpdate(child);
            childWrapperDao.createOrUpdate(generateWrapper(parent, child));
        }
    }
}
```

I've got original speed up on a specific Android4.2/MIPS set-top-box (STB).
`callBatchTasks` was the first option because that's what we use througout all the code and it works well.

```
parentDao.callBatchTasks(
    // ...
    saveData();
    // ...
);
```

But inserts were slow, so we've tried to nest `callBatchTasks` for every used DAO, set autocommit off, startThreadConnection and probably something else - don't remember at the moment. To no avail.

From my own experience and other similar posts it seems the problem occurs when several tables/DAOs are involved and it has something to do with implemetation specifics of Android (or SQLite) for concrete devices.

Comment: This made a significant difference for me! I went from 6 minutes to 1.868 seconds! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I will be pleased if anyone response. I am not getting any improvement with approach over the callBatchTasks() method. I am testing with 5000 objects to insert in db and both approach giving me same milliseconds and it's around 5000 ms.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet hmm... that's slow. Are you sure you are really measuring inserts ? Probably there are some other expensive operations in the loop ? Calculations, XML parsing/validation maybe ?

Comment: I have written 3 method. First one is casual insert with ormlite, second one with orm batch isnert, third is according to your approach. Would you please take a look at my methods. [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10758607) I didn't figure out any differences between callBatchTasks() and your approach.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet Your code looks good to me - can't see the problem. A few things to check: **1.** Make sure `mDatabaseHelper.getStoryDao()` is cheap, or move it out of loop. **2.** Try to exclude ORMLite completely - run raw SQL-insert, i.e. `INSERT INTO story(...) VALUES(...)` in SQLite transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your continues response. We use ORM to do CRUD operations by methods. Ins't ? How can I generate INSERT SQL for an object easily ? I don't want to write or generate INSERT raw SQL myself.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet yeah, I'm not proposing to replace it everywhere - just that one loop, for test. If raw SQL turns out to be faster, then we should dig deeper inside ORMLite. But if it's about the same - problem is somewhere else. About generation - I don't know. You can get a list of columns by logging `dao.queryBuilder().prepare().getStatement()`. Then you probably can build a template string (such as what you use in `String.format(...)`, e.g. "INSERT INTO story(`_id`, `name`) VALUES(%d, %s)" ) and  generate a bunch of `INSERT`s in a loop.

Comment: This is exactly what `callBatchTasks(...)` does.  I don't think it would be any faster.

Comment: AlexanderMalakhov What about what @Gray said? Do you really detected that it is faster to do the transaction instead of using callBatchTasks?

Comment: Any sort of Java performance test should be run _much_ longer.  The first couple of seconds is class loading and other issues.  Maybe try your test 100 times or something to get good numbers.  As it is, if you are talking about milliseconds then it's a coin flip.

Comment: @Gray no no, results are stable - I've ran original test (on STB) 10s of times and deviation is about 3%. And the code is exected long after app start. On Xperia I've ran it just a couple of times for each approach, so yeah, results are not very indicative to say wich way is faster. But my point is there is no order of magnitude slowdown when using `callBatchTasks`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are slowing somewhat because you are doing two IO tasks at one time (at least in the code shown above).  You are reading from a file and writing to a database (which is a file). Also, from what I understand transactions should be a reasonable size.  1600 seems like a very high number. I would start with 100 but play around with the size.

So essentially I suggest you "chunk" your reads and inserts.

Read 100 lines to a temp Array, then insert that 100.  Then read the next 100, then insert, etc.